# Actualizar último registro en mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

tengo una función cuyo propósito es actualizar la hora de salida de un usuario. La base de datos está programada para crear un registro con el nombre, la fecha y la hora de entrada, la hora de salida queda en null. La idea que que cuando se cierre el programa, la base de datos coja el último registro de esa columna y actualize la hora de salida. Estoy tratando de usar el comando **ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1** Para seleccionar el último registro, pero la terminal me arroja que la sintaxis está mal. Si alguien sabe cómo corregirlo, gracias.

He intentado varias formas **(porner un WHERE antes de ORDER, por ejemplo)** pero todas me arrojan error.

UPDATE: Cambié la sintaxis pero todavía no funciona, creé una llave primaria numérica para poner en la condición WHERE pero no funcionó:

```
cursor1.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Registro_de_sesion(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Nombre TEXT, Fecha TEXT, Hora_inicio TEXT, Hora_salida TEXT)''')
```

Y aquí la nueva función:

```
def salir():
        Ventana1.destroy()
        conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
        cursor1=conn.cursor()
        
        cursor1.execute('''UPDATE  Registro_de_sesion SET Hora_salida=%s WHERE ID=(SELECT ID FROM Registro_de_sesion ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)'''.format(variable_hora.get()))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "ultimo registro"? Que hace de un registro el ultimo? El ultimo que se ingresó? La fecha más grande?

Comment: Por cierto, si mi respuesta en tu pregunta anterior te sirvió, estaría agradecido de que la aceptes c:

Comment: @DanteS. Lo haré ni bien termine con esta parte Y sí, resondiendo a tu pregunta, es el último registro ingresado ya que crea uno nuevo cada vez que alguien inicia sesión

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta para mostrar otra cosa que se me ocurrió de repente pero tampoco funcionó

Comment: Dale! Y una consulta. Que cosa no funciona en tu update? Tal como lo veo, estás mesclando el viejo formateo de cadenas con el nuevo. (%s y format). Si tu código original es así, debería de darte un error donde está el %s. Por lo demás, creo que ese es el camino correcto.

Comment: La terminal imprime: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE ID=(SELECT ID FROM Registro_de_sesion ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)' at line 1**

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140837/discussion-between-dante-s-and-carlos-arraez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba escribiendo esta respuesta en el momento que pusiste la tuya, pero igual, ahi va, como información complementaria.

Un error que tienes es porque estás haciendo un reemplazo de una cadena directo en la consulta sin entrecomillarlo y el otro es que `%s` no funciona con `format`

Para arreglarlo:

```py
'''UPDATE Registro_de_sesion SET Hora_salida='{}' WHERE 
ID=(SELECT ID FROM Registro_de_sesion ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)'''.format(variable_hora.get())
```

Sin embargo, lo anterior no es la forma recomendada de manejar las consultas ([ver documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-tutorial-cursorbuffered.html)) por lo de las [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+inyeccion+sql), entonces debe quedar,

```py
# ...
cursor1.execute('''UPDATE Registro_de_sesion SET Hora_salida=%s WHERE 
ID=(SELECT ID FROM Registro_de_sesion ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)''', (variable_hora.get(),))
conn.commit()
# ...
```

Comment: @DanteS. Lo revisaré mañana, se me acabó el tiempo por hoy

Comment: @carlosarraez no entiendo lo que me quieres decir. Por que es un comentario en la respuesta de aeportugal?

Comment: Lo puse ahí por error

Answer (score 1):

aquí dejo la solución que me funcionó para que le sirva a alguien:

```
def salir():
        Ventana1.destroy()
        conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
        cursor1=conn.cursor()
        cursor1.execute('''SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Registro_de_sesion''')
        (nombre, )=cursor1.fetchone()
        hora=variable_hora.get()
        cursor1.execute('''UPDATE  Registro_de_sesion SET Hora_salida=('{0}') WHERE ID=('{1}')'''.format(hora, nombre))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Gracias :)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).